# How to make a UITextView selectable but not editable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm making an iPad application that will let certain selected words or sentences be spoken out loud. But for this I should be able to select text by just dragging a finger over the words.

I was thinking about using a UITextView since you can get the selected text from it but it always shows up the keyboard and the magnifying glass with then the menu for Select, Select All and copy. Is it possible to just select words (preferable from a UILabel)? If not is it possible with only the magnifying glass showing but no menu and keyboard?

Maybe I'm googling wrong but I've spent already many hours looking for a solution and I'm just not making any progress...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

to stop key board to come up you can do it in

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
  {

  [textView resignFirstResponder];

}

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I do that and try to select something the magnifying glass shows and the keyboard also pops up...

Comment: Aparantly you just have to enter the following code "textView.editable = NO;" which has a different functionality than disabling this in the interface builder. Now the keyboard does not show but I have to find a way to automatically start selecting instead of giving the menu to select/select all.